# Shade smooth not working in blender

Tags: modeling

I already tried to flip normals,merge by distance, nothing changed, also nothing is marked as sharp [image]

[image]

Comment: hello maybe in the Object Data > Geometry Data > Clear Custom Split Normals Data, or could you please share your file?

Comment: here it is [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=XqKm6ZqA" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/XqKm6ZqA/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have faces beneath your object, so the smooth won't work correctly between the other faces, just remove them:

[image]

Also as pointed out by 3fingeredfrog, you have inverted normal, so select all in *Edit* mode and press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>N</kbd>.

At last, shade smooth again in *Object* mode.

Comment: After dealing with the inside faces you will still find problems with "hard edges" because you you have some inverted face normals. Instead of using the "Flip normals" option use  "Calculate Outside", SHFT N.

Comment: @3fingeredfrog you're right, I saw it first but it was not enough to fix the problem, but I must not forget to point it out   ;)

Comment: it is worked. but not everywhere

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=R74vBOR5" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/R74vBOR5/)

Comment: @Николай Пильчук Shade Smooth again